# Android Studio edit text numeric type

Tags: java, android, parsing, integer

I need to store an integer value into database, so I need to convert the value of the textfields into integers and for some reason I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.widget.EditText{431fbec VFED..CL. ........ 0,250-1080,386 #7f0b0076
```

I set the `editText` to be number type, but when I want to add the value of that field to the integer variable I get the exception above.

```
Integer year = Integer.parseInt(editTextYear.toString());
```

This line of code is the problem;  I tried to first create the string and then parse the value to int but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is your input when you get exception?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getText()` property to get input from `EditText`. `toString()` property on object will return you object representation in `String` form.

```
final String input = editTextYear.getText().toString(); // To get input and 
                                                       // then parse it
if(input!= null)
Integer year = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rasi is essentially right, but I'd use isEmpty instead of null.

So instead of

```
editTextYear.toString()
```

it should be

```
editTextYear.getText().toString()
```

but to avoid a nullpointerexception, just do:

```
if(!input.isEmpty)
```

to avoid having either an empty or a null value there